How can i make a select start at a specific point without using selected
We have this select to select year of birth.
Looking at the statistics of last couple of years, most users (close to 70%) are between the ages of 26-34.
When the user opens the select, We want it to start at around 1994 (or age 30), but without selecting '1994' as a default, we can't seem to make this work.
I do not want 1994 selected by default, as I want to check if the select is actually selected.
This is our current setup for the select:
<select name="year" required>
   <option value="" disabled selected> - </option>
   <?php for ($i = date('Y') - 110; $i <= date('Y'); $i++) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if ($i == $year) echo 'selected'; ?>>
         <?php echo $i; ?>
      </option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>

I've looked for a javascript/jquery solution. Found and tried this:
$(document).ready(function() {
            
            const yearToScroll = 1994;
            const birthYearSelect = $('#geboortedatum_jaar');

            // Find the option index of 1994
            const optionIndex = birthYearSelect.find('option[value="' + yearToScroll + '"]').index();

            // Set the scroll position of the dropdown to show 1994
            birthYearSelect.prop('selectedIndex', -1); // Ensures no option is selected
            birthYearSelect[0].selectedIndex = optionIndex;
            
});

But this still selects the '1994' option, making it no different from just putting selected on the 1994 option and not just scroll to that position when opening the select.

Yeah, using "selectedIndex" makes it selected, unsurprisingly. Pretty sure you can't scroll a dropdown's options programmatically unfortunately without choosing a value. But maybe someone will contradict me

You won't be able to achieve this with the standard HTML select control. You'd need either a custom control, where you can set the scroll position, or use a text input and let users type the year themselves to save scrolling

Besides what's already pointed out, you forgot also to add the ID geboortedatum_jaar to the Select box, and also, instead of hardcoding 1994 you should use new Date().getFullYear() - 30

The built-in select's "drop down" is not part of the DOM, it's part of the browser, so you have very little control over it from javascript.

It is impossible using the standard DOM select
Here is a select2 version


const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const minAge = 18;
const maxAge = 40;

const $dob = $('#dob');

for (let age = minAge; age <= maxAge; age++) {
  const birthYear = currentYear - age;
  $dob.append(`<option value="${birthYear}">${birthYear} (age ${age})</option>`)
}


$dob
  .select2({
    'width': '150px'
  })
  .select2('open');

const targetValue = currentYear - 30;
const $targetItem = $(`li.select2-results__option[id*="${targetValue}"]`);

if ($targetItem.length > 0) {
  const $dropdown = $('.select2-results__options'); // This is the dropdown container
  $dropdown.scrollTop($targetItem.offset().top - $dropdown.offset().top + $dropdown.scrollTop());
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="dob" name="dob">
  <option value="">Please select DOB</option>
</select>




One possible solution, is to add a disabled option in the position you want, eg:
<option selected disabled>select year</option>

if you place this approximately 10 values below the one you want in the middle, then (in my version of Chrome at least) when the user drops down the select, the value you want will be in the middle.
This may be browser dependent.


for (let i=2024; i>1950; --i) {
  $("select").append(`<option>${i}</option>`);
  if (i == (2024-30-10))
    $("select").append(`<option selected disabled>select year</option>`);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
</select>



(jquery just to populate the select, not needed otherwise)
While this may provide a solution, tbh, it looks a but rubbish.  I recommend a third-party plugin / drop-down replacement, but this may be a solution if that's not an option.

This is clever, though.
